# Django view argument in decorator

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-views

am having a function ill like to make into a decorator with an argument please can any one help with this

```
def get_permission(request,permission_level):
    if has_permission(request,permission_level):#this is another function
        #my work will be done here
    else:
        raise Http404
```

and ill just want to use it in my view like this

```
@get_permission(permission_level)
def a_view(request)
```

can any one help out on this please? thanks

Comment: what your get permission do you want to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding Python decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators)

Comment: your level of permission determines if you can get that view or not so so views have permission associated with them.so ill pass the views permission in the decorator so ill not need to alter my code

Comment: maybe you can get idea from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269444/permission-required-decorator-not-working-for-me

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [django/contrib/auth/decorators.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py), something like

```
from functools import wraps
from django.utils.decorators import available_attrs

def get_permission(permission_level):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func, assigned=available_attrs(func))
        def _wrapped(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if has_permission(request, permission_level): 
                'special logic goes here...'
                return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise Http404
```

Check [How to make a chain of function decorators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators) and [PEP 318](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) for writing decorators.

Or you could take advantage of `user_passes_test` or `permission_required` in [django/contrib/auth/decorators.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.4.x/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py) directly, if the decorator just checks the permission to determine the result to return.